# C Newbie: Help with Simple Function

Tags: c

Spoiler: I am an absolute beginner to C. I quickly threw threw together this program to test my knowledge, but my compiler is giving me errors. What is the problem and why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char *string = "abcdefghi";

    printf("%s\n\n", string);

    printf("%s\n\n", substr(string, 1, 2));
}

char * substr(char *string, int start, int length)
{
    int i;
    char *temp;

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = string[i+start];
    }

    return temp;
}
```

EDIT:

Sorry, it's like 1 AM here, I've been up trying to figure this out.

The errors are:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:9: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
main.c: At top level:
main.c:12: error: conflicting types for ‘substr’
```

Comment: Are you going to tell us what error you get, or are we supposed to guess?

Comment: Read your compiler errors. They will help you answer your question.

Comment: Sorry, but I figured with such a small amount of code, and such a simple issue, I wouldn't need to write my error messages. My mistake.

Comment: Always call gcc with the options `-Wall -Wextra -Os` and learn to understand the warning messages you get from these options. This will make you a careful programmer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the errors I see:

### Use of uninitialized pointer

In `substr` you declare `char *temp;` and then use it without initializing it to anything.  This is not a compile-time error, but this program will almost certainly crash when you run it, since `temp` will effectively point to a random memory address.  This is a case of *undefined behavior*, and C is chock full of it.  Undefined behavior will come out of nowhere and eat your pets if you aren't careful.

Consider `malloc()`ing some memory, or having your function receive a pointer to a buffer where it can write the portion of the string.

### Use of function not yet declared

In C you must declare functions before they are used, or at least declare their prototype.  Above `main()`'s declaration, add this line:

```
char * substr(char *string, int start, int length);
```

### No use of `const` where it makes sense

When assigning a string literal to a `char*`, that variable should be declared `const`.  So change

```
char *string = "abcdefghi";
```

to

```
const char *string = "abcdefghi";
```

You will have to change your function prototype to

```
char * substr(const char *string, int start, int length)
```

which is what it should have been in the first place.

**Added 2010-12-02:**

### `substr()` does not add terminating null character

The `substr()` function, while algorithmically correct in every other sense, does not add a terminating null character to the new string.  This will cause `printf()` and every other string-using function (like `strlen()`, `strcpy()`, etc.) to run off the end of the string into unallocated heap memory, or stack memory (depending on how you resolve the "uninitialized pointer" issue).

To fix this, add this line immediately after the `for` loop, and before the `return` statement:

```
temp[i] = '\0';
```

Note that this should not be added *in* the for loop, as that would have the effect of creating a string with zero length.

Comment: "When assigning a string literal to a char*, that variable should be declared const." Why?

Comment: @moteutsch: Compile and run this program to see why: `#include <stdio.h> int main() { char *a = "hello"; char *b = "hello"; a[0] = 'f'; printf("%s\n", b); return 0; }`  If you get any output you will be lucky -- it will probably just segfault on you, because on many OSes the memory page used to store string literals is not writable.  Declaring the pointer `const` will allow the compiler to prevent you from manipulating the data it points to.  If the program does run, the output will probably be "fello", because most compilers will unify identical string literals into one string resource.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious error is that you need to include a prototype in your code...

```
char * substr(char *string, int start, int length);

main()
...
```

Otherwise your program will not be aware that substr has been defined (as a function) below the main code.

Comment: but see cdhowie's post for a more comprehensive list :~)

Answer (score 1):

First, the return type of `main` is `int`.  Second, you have to declare functions before they're used. Either reorder `main` and `substr`, or put a prototype for `substr` in before your `main` definition. Third, temp is not initialized.  You either need to `malloc()` space for it, or allocate a static buffer (not on the stack).

Comment: `main` is allowed to return `void` in some C dialects (if not most).

Comment: @cdhowie: See C99 5.1.2.2.1. The standard requires main to have a return type of int. Compilers that let you fudge this are noncompliant (if ubiquitous).

Comment: Or perhaps they implement C89?

Answer (score 0):

Compiler issues:
No prototype for substr. Your compiler will probably let this go if you aren't compiling with strict ansi/iso standards.

Some runtime issues:
You didn't allocate any space for *temp. When you declare a local variable without initializing it, it holds a garbage value. Since temp is a pointer to a character, temp's content is a pointer to some address which most probably doesn't belong to you.

Answer (score -1):

On the last iteration of that `for` loop, `i` will index into the last position of the string. But you're adding the value of `start` (1 in this case) to `i` and *then* indexing into the string - meaning you're likely getting an index out-of-bounds error on that last loop iteration.

The fix (assuming I've correctly diagnosed the problem): initialize `i` to `start` instead of adding `start` to `i`.

Comment: Take another look at the string he's passing, and the values of `start` and `length`.

Comment: @Anon. Whoops, you're right. That said, his `substr` implementation *is* going to suffer from the problem I'm describing. Just not in this case.

Comment: That depends on the meaning ascribed to `length`. If it takes its usual meaning of "how many characters to extract from the string", then no, it won't be an issue.